# KSQL Java Client app Received 404 response from server:

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have written KSQL Client Java app to fetch the topic message details from KSQL Tables. This is the code snippet to read the topic messages from KSQL table. But when i run this program getting below error. Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

KSQLClient Code:

```java
ClientOptions options = ClientOptions.create()
                   .setHost(KSQLDB_SERVER_HOST)
                   .setPort(KSQLDB_SERVER_HOST_PORT);
Client client = Client.create(options);
              
System.out.println("Client object value ---->"+client);
// Send requests with the client by following the other examples
               
String query = "SELECT * FROM TESTKSQLTBLE EMIT CHANGES;";
Map<String, Object> properties = Collections.singletonMap("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
client.streamQuery(query, properties)
   .thenAccept(streamedQueryResult -> {
       System.out.println("Result column names: " + streamedQueryResult.columnNames());
   
       // RowSubscriber subscriber = new RowSubscriber();
       //streamedQueryResult.subscribe(subscriber);
   }).exceptionally(e -> {
       System.out.println("Push query request failed: " + e);
       return null;
   });
```

### Exception details:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.confluent.ksql.api.client.exception.KsqlClientException: Received 404 response from server: HTTP 404 Not Found. Error code: 40400
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.geta(Unknown Source)
        at my.ksqldb.app.KSQLExampleApp.main(KSQLExampleApp.java:55)
```